# How to copy object property to other object and then remove this object from array?

Tags: javascript

If object name the same I want to copy `source` property and then remove this object from array. How I can implement it?

```js
const data = [
    {name: "name1", source: "source1"},
    {name: "name1", source: "source2"},
    {name: "name2", source: "source3"},
    {name: "name3", source: "source4"},
    {name: "name4", source: "source5"},
]
```

expected result

```
[
  {name: "name1", source: "source1, source2"},
  {name: "name2", source: "source3"},
  {name: "name3", source: "source4"},
  {name: "name4", source: "source5"},
]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Array.prototype.reduce`, you can group the values by `name` key value and also merge the `source` key values of same `name` key.

```js
const data = [
  {name: "name1", source: "source1"},
  {name: "name1", source: "source2"},
  {name: "name2", source: "source3"},
  {name: "name3", source: "source4"},
  {name: "name4", source: "source5"},
];

const groupBy = data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.name] ? acc[cur.name].source += `,${cur.source}` : acc[cur.name] = cur;
  return acc;
}, {});

const output = Object.values(groupBy);
console.log(output);
```